# Finding the Highest and Lowest in the entered 10 numbers

Tags: java

i made a code recently on our class but i couldn't understand what i really did. do i have problems with my logic because i cant understand the Double.MIN_VALUE and the Double.MAX_VALUE.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Exer32_HighestLowest
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        double highest =Double.MIN_VALUE;
        double lowest =Double.MAX_VALUE;
        double num= 0;
        for(int i=0; i<10; i++)
        {
            System.out.println("Enter your score");
            num = sc.nextDouble();
            if (num > highest)
            {
                highest = num;
            }
            if(num < lowest)
            {
                lowest = num;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("The Highest Score is: "+highest);
        System.out.println("The Lowest Score is: "+lowest);
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks for your response, but i made this code while my professor was not around i just experimented this the whole time.

Comment: Did you read the documentation? https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For `double highest = Double.MIN_VALUE;`, instead use `-Double.MAX_VALUE`. Note the '-' sign.

And for :

```
if (num > highest)
        {
            highest = num;
        }
```

Use:

```
highest = Math.max(highest, num)
lowest = Math.min(lowest, num)
```

Comment: how about for the double lowest? should i change it or nah?

Comment: the variable that i declared. as double lowest = Double.MAX_vALUE? sorry if im too annoying now lol

Comment: @Francis yes the lowest you can set at the max value indeed

Answer (score 0):

Double.MIN_VALUE:
A constant holding the smallest positive nonzero value of type double.

Double.MAX_VALUE:
A constant holding the largest positive finite value of type double.

You can check here for more details: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html